# Model identifiability in SEM

Tags: missing-data, structural-equation-modeling, identifiability

I am trying to fit a model with a structure similar to others already published (see Nees et al., 2012 Neuropsychopharmacology).

In particular, the model structure is organized in 3 latent variables (A, B and C) predicting a further latent variable (D).
A, B and C derive from 3 observed variables each, while C derives from 5.

I have a sample of 263 subjects with missing values not exceeding 10%.

Why my model is unidentified?

(I am using AMOS)

Thanks a lot for ypur help!

Livia

Comment: Try to replace/impute missings. Will the analysis work?

Comment: Thanks for your anwer. I was informed that by checking the "evaluate mean and intercepts" botton in AMOS, missing values would be imputed with the FIML estimation. Is that what you mean? thanks

Comment: Your model is probably not identified because you didn't put in a necessary constraint. However, it's also possible for a model to be empirically under-identified - that is, it might be identified with other data, but is not identified with your data. I don't thank any one can tell without knowing more about your model.

Comment: Also, this is not amos specific. It's about SEM, so I edited the question title.